# Debugging ASP.Net Core 1.1 MVC source code in Visual Studio 2017 RC

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

Earlier debugging ASP.Net Core MVC source code in Visual studio 2015 was very easy using global.json file. Has anyone tried to debug ASP.Net Core MVC source code in Visual Studio 2017 RC? Is it possible at all in VS 2017 RC? Can someone who has been successful in debugging MVC source code in VS 2017 RC list down steps please?

**Update**:
I tried setting up symbol source as mentioned in comment by Tseng. However its still not able to load symbols. Its not even searching symbol source https://nuget.smbsrc.net/.
Following is symbol server setting.
[image]

Following is fiddler screenshot.
[image]

Comment: Did you even try out the traditional approach?? (Right click solution -> Properties -> Common Properties -> Debug Source Files?)

Comment: @Tseng : Yup, I did try that option but VS was not able to download symbols for MVC assemblies from symbol server. Is there any specific symbol server settings I need to use for MVC related symbols?

Comment: Did you tried adding the symbol source as noted here http://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/symbol-packages ?

Comment: @Tseng: Updated question with outcome of suggestion in previous comment.

Comment: @PankajKapare did you solve the issue? I have the same now and don't know what to do

Comment: @arthur.borisow: Unfortunately haven't been successful yet.

Comment: @PankajKapare Any updates here please?

Comment: This shows you how to debug ASP.NET Core source code:
https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-debug-asp-net-core-source-code-448544c16473?sk=58f24ef1f6b39d0bd2927cd36dbd690c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to debug the `asp.net core 2.0` source code in Visual Studio 2017. We have to follow the next steps:

1. If we have already downloaded Visual Studio 2017, we check that our version is at least `15.3` (help -> about Microsoft visual studio). If it is not, then we update by clicking the yellow flag in the right upper corner. We might also have to download the `SDK version 2.0` separately.

   After updating visual studio 2017, we open command prompt and we execute the      command `dotnet --version` to identify the current SDK version. If it is prior than 2.0.0 version, then we have to also download the latest SDK version release. We can also check any older installed versions of SDK in `C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk`.
2. The required packages for master branch in asp.net core open source code in github must be downloaded from `myget.org` repository. The default `nuget.org` repository is not the appropriate one. Thus we go to `tools -> nugget package manager -> package manager settings -> nugget package manager -> package sources` and we click the plus (+) button to add the two new repositories. The required package repository for SDK is `https://dotnet.myget.org/F/aspnetcore-tools/api/v3/index.json`, while the package repository for master branch is `https://dotnet.myget.org/F/aspnetcore-master/api/v3/index.json`. We click `update` for each of the new repository and then we `OK`.
3. We go to `github.com/aspnet` and supposing that we want to debug the MVC source code, we click on `MVC` link and then we click on `releases` link. We download the `release 2.0.0` with tag `rel/2.0.0`.
4. We unzip the file and we go to `src` folder. In all the project folders inside `src` folder, we have to change the inner text of the `<TargetFramework>` xml node in each of the `*.csproj` files, from `netstandard2.0` to `netcoreapp2.0`. The change should be the following one:

   `<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>`
5. We create a new `asp.net core 2.0` project in Visual Studio 2017. We have to pay attention to select `asp.net core 2.0` in the next Window because the default selection is `asp.net core 1.1`.

   [asp.net core 2.0 selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPzqC.jpg)
6. In our new created `asp.net core 2.0` project, we have to add a project reference in `{project_name}.csproj` file. We right click the project in solution explorer and select `edit {project_name}.csproj`. We add the following xml text inside it:

`<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="{mvc_solution_directory_path}\src\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>`

`{mvc_solution_directory_path}` is the directory path where we unzipped the source code from github and where the `mvc.sln` file is located.

7. Now we have to add each one of the projects located in `src` folder of the `MVC` open source code. We right click our solution in solution explorer and select `add -> existing project`.
8. We are ready to build our solution.

Trying to debug `asp.net core 1.1` by downloading the respective open source version from github, is quite problematic. I have uploaded to [github](https://github.com/ileve/debug-netcoreapp2.0) a small utility which automates the steps 4 – 7. I hope that this guide helps. I tested it both in Windows 7 and Windows 10 and i was able to debug the open source code.

Comment: Though instructions are debugging asp.net core 2.0 but are quite helpful.